# Mysql - JOIN function - returns two values when same filter criteria are met

Tags: mysql, join

I am using the following code to extract the latest balance value (by date and time) for every week out of my database:

```
SELECT t.id, t.date, t.time, t.balance FROM db1 t 
JOIN (SELECT tt.cw, MAX(timestamp(tt.date,tt.time)) as 'maxtime' 
FROM db1 tt GROUP BY tt.cw) m ON m.maxtime = timestamp(t.date,t.time) AND t.cw = m.cw;
```

The code works fine, however I experienced the following issue:

Whenever the latest value has exactly the same timestamp (when two entries are done at exactly the same second) the result shows both rows with the respective values. Now I somehow want the query only to display one value per week.

I tried some DISTINCT versions, which all didn't work.

Many thanks for your help!
Cheers

:UPDATE:
Here an example of the structure of db1:

```
+----+------------+-------+----+---------+
| id |    date    | time  | cw | balance |
+----+------------+-------+----+---------+
|  1 | 2015-01-01 | 13:01 |  1 |     100 |
|  2 | 2015-01-01 | 17:01 |  1 |     110 |
|  3 | 2015-01-02 | 14:01 |  1 |     120 |
|  4 | 2015-01-15 | 13:01 |  3 |     140 |
|  5 | 2015-01-15 | 13:01 |  3 |     140 |
+----+------------+-------+----+---------+
```

The result looks like that:

```
+----+------------+-------+----+---------+
| id |    date    | time  | cw | balance |
+----+------------+-------+----+---------+
|  3 | 2015-01-02 | 14:01 |  1 |     120 |
|  4 | 2015-01-15 | 13:01 |  3 |     140 |
|  5 | 2015-01-15 | 13:01 |  3 |     140 |
+----+------------+-------+----+---------+
```

But should only deliver that:

```
+----+------------+-------+----+---------+
| id |    date    | time  | cw | balance |
+----+------------+-------+----+---------+
|  3 | 2015-01-02 | 14:01 |  1 |     120 |
|  5 | 2015-01-15 | 13:01 |  3 |     140 |
+----+------------+-------+----+---------+
```

Comment: `show create table db1` output please. Sample data, desired results. So 3 things

Comment: I put the sample data in the question above, thanks

Comment: Either you have not shown the entire table or there is something wrong with your design. What does the `id` field represent? If it's just an incrementing value then your model is broken; how do you relate the balance to an account? Seems you need something else to make the balance rows unique.

Comment: he appears to have a running balance dependent on `cw`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this suffices without a long winded explanation, as you were 99% there. I am banking on the auto_increment of `id`:

```
create table db1
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    date date not null,
    time time not null,
    cw int not null,
    balance decimal(10,2) not null
);
insert db1 (date,time,cw,balance) values ('2015-01-01','13:01',1,100);
insert db1 (date,time,cw,balance) values ('2015-01-01','17:01',1,110);
insert db1 (date,time,cw,balance) values ('2015-01-02','14:01',1,120);
insert db1 (date,time,cw,balance) values ('2015-01-15','13:01',3,140);
insert db1 (date,time,cw,balance) values ('2015-01-15','13:01',3,140);

SELECT t.id, t.date, t.time, t.balance 
FROM db1 t 
JOIN 
(   SELECT tt.cw, MAX(id) as 'max_id' 
    FROM db1 tt 
    GROUP BY tt.cw
) m 
ON t.id=m.max_id;

+----+------------+----------+---------+
| id | date       | time     | balance |
+----+------------+----------+---------+
|  3 | 2015-01-02 | 14:01:00 |  120.00 |
|  5 | 2015-01-15 | 13:01:00 |  140.00 |
+----+------------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: That's it. Key was the increasing ID. I was thinking a bit too complicated here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If u want one and only one out put use Group by.

after you query just add

```
GROUP BY id,cw desc Having Max(date) =t.date and Max(time)=t.time;
```

Sorry i couldn't write the actual query please modify the query to your actual use.

Comment: Your way of using the Join is complex.And It has to be executed.